# Define a Template column for Kendo MVC Grid in Razor syntax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid

I using Kendo UI (Version Q2 2015 SP2) in my MVC project.

I want use template column in my view.

but my problem is that when the page loaded completely the template cell will be empty.

I realized that when disable jQuery, my problem will be solved. but other section does not work.

my jQuery version is 1.9.1

and my view code is this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).HtmlAttributes(new { })
          .Name("grid")
          .Pageable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .Scrollable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .Filterable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.LangTitle).Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LangTitle).ToString()).Width(130);
              columns.Bound(p => p.LangCountry).Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LangCountry).ToString()).Width(130);
              columns.Bound(p => p.LangEncode).Title(Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LangEncode).ToString()).Width(130);
              columns.Template(x => @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @x.LangId }));
          })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
        )
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    )
```

How can show template column correctly?